# Moongose schema type for Chrono Time (hh:mm:ss)?

Tags: mongoose, mean-stack, mongoose-schema

I'm developing a MEAN app and I'm not sure which strategy is optimal for storing chrono time (e.g. Track&Field time lap).

Looking up for some Mongoose schema types, I couldn't find any that suit my needs.

Any idea?

thanks,